# Joomla 3 redirect after wrong login try

Tags: redirect, joomla, authentication

Iam using the login module of Joomla. Login and Logout redirects to the pages which are set in the modul settings.

My problem is the status, where a user tries to login with wrong user credentials. In this case, the user will be redirected to component/users/?view=login page. In my case, this page is not in use and also not designed like the rest of the pages. Therefore I would like to redirect the user, after a wrong login, to the previous page.

Does anybody have a clue, how to solve that?

thx

Comment: Do you have access and the ability to edit the template code?

Comment: of course, I can do that.

Comment: Check my answer, it's proven practice and it should help. If you have any questions, I'll be more than happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify users controller. But to keep it "update proof" you cannot modify the core code, thats why we will make an override:

1. Go to the `components/com_users/controllers/` and duplicate a file called `user.php`, you can call a new file `user2.php`
2. Open `user2.php` file and rename controller class to `UsersControllerUser2`
3. Create a template override of your login module (to make it update proof also), create a `templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/mod_login` folder and copy `modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php` file there.
4. Open file created in step 3 and change login module task from `<input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.login" />` to `<input type="hidden" name="task" value="user2.login" />`
5. Open user2.php file once again, and modify this part of code (around lines 77-82):

> $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login',
>   false));

Change `$app->redirect` route to whatever you want :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with a template override for the mod_login module.  This link details the specifics of how to do that.

http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Basically, you copy the file located at /modules/mod_login/tmpl/default_login.php to /templates/{YOUR_TEMPLATE}/html/mod_login and this is what Joomla will use to render any mod_login modules as long as you keep the file name the same.

At line 116 you will see this line of code:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $return; ?>" />
```

You now have full programmatic control of what the return value should be. I usually pass the base64 encoded return param in the URL, which I in turn parse and insert as the value of the return hidden input in my module template override

A side note, you should never alter core files or place custom files along side core files for a variety a reason, the primary being any subsequent Joomla update could wipe out your changes breaking your website.

Comment: This is a vey nice approach. The problem is, that the link ($return variable) cannot be edited for the situation login=wrong. When I decode $return it will show me the link to the proper following page. Furthermore if I try to sign in, the mod_login view wont be touched a second time, where I could adjust the target link. So how can I declare the wanted link in case of wrong login with this approach?

Comment: In these situations i usually handle user login via an AJAX call to the custom component endpoint which instantiate the native Joomla user model for authentication and routing. Is there a custom component you could add a dedicated controller to meet this need? If not, next best thing is to apply template override to the com_user login view where you can insert a redirect using JFactory::getApplication()->redirect() at very top.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.6.1 in order to stay in the same page after a wrong login, you have to change a line in /components/com_users/controllers/user.php

Find:

```
if (true !== $app->login($credentials, $options))
    {
        // Login failed !
        // Clear user name, password and secret key before sending the login form back to the user.
        $data['remember'] = (int) $options['remember'];
        $data['username'] = '';
        $data['password'] = '';
        $data['secretkey'] = '';
        $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', $data);
        $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));
```

and just comment the last line:

```
        // $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

di3sel great override, still working on 2019, in your step 3 you could add:

3. Create a template override of your login module (to make it update proof also), create a templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/mod_login folder and copy modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php file there with a different name like altlogin.php
4. In the admin area open yout mod_login, in the advanced tab you'll find "Presentation", and select the view you created in step 3 "altlogin" from your template.

Thanks.