# Joomla 3 redirect after wrong login try in modal login

Tags: authentication, joomla, module, overriding, materialize

I had override my login module to made a modal login with materialize-stepper framwork (this works fine). But my problem is that when I enter the wrong password, the modal is closed and I'm redirected to x page. I saw these other [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145386/joomla-3-redirect-after-wrong-login-try) but these do not help me. Do you have any idea that How I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try catching the event from plugin here is document page: https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User
and the event you need is **onUserLoginFailure**